# update field in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to update the `plateNumber` in my table car.

I used this for a specific ID:

```
car.update({_id:'436' }, {$set: {plateNumber: 'DG-884-AQ'}}, {multi: true},cb);
```

But It didn't work, and I got

> `ReferenceError: cb is not defined`

What should I do?
and I use car as instance or Car as the model.

Thanks.

Comment: the `ReferenceError: cb` means that the update function is not able to find the callback function `cb`. You need to pass a proper callback function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a function:

```
car.update(
  {_id:'436' },
  {$set: {plateNumber: 'DG-884-AQ'}},
  {multi: true},
  (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      // handle error
    } else {
      // handle success
    }
  }
);
```

Your code would work if you had the `cb` function defined with:

```
  let cb = (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      // handle error
    } else {
      // handle success
    }
  };
```

or:

```
  function cb(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      // handle error
    } else {
      // handle success
    }
  }
```

but you cannot pass `cb` as an argument if you don't have it defined.

Answer (score 1):

`cb` is suppose to be a function(callback)

```
car.update(
    {_id:'436' }, 
    {$set: {plateNumber: 'DG-884-AQ'}}, 
    {multi: true}, function(err, resp) {
});
```